# Why is my form not sending from a p tag on click?

Tags: javascript, forms, jquery, form-submit

I have a form I am sending and currently it uses a p tag with a class of .button-like. For some reason o get no response at all and not submission in the network tab of my chrome dev tools? Can any help?

```
$(".button-like").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var $thisItem = $(this);
        var $parent = $thisItem.parent(".forms");
        $parent.submit(function () {
            var data = {
                "action": "like"
            };
            data = $parent.serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            var itemId = $parent.find('input.id').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/actions/",
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Like submitted successfully sent');
                    $('body').addClass('liked');
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

Thanks,
Mark

Comment: You're not calling the submit event, you're setting it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(".button-like").each(function () {
    $(this).click(function () {
        var $thisItem = $(this);
        var $parent = $thisItem.parent(".forms");
        $parent.submit(function () {
            var data = {
                "action": "like"
            };
            data = $parent.serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
            var itemId = $parent.find('input.id').val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/actions/",
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log('Like submitted successfully sent');
                    $('body').addClass('liked');
                }
            });
            return false;
        }).submit();
    });
});
```

This will trigger the submit right after setting it. But I think what you want to do is:

```
$(".button-like").each(function () {
    var $thisItem = $(this);
    var $parent = $thisItem.parent(".forms");
    $parent.submit(function () {
        var data = {
            "action": "like"
        };
        data = $parent.serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
        var itemId = $parent.find('input.id').val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/actions/",
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log('Like submitted successfully sent');
                $('body').addClass('liked');
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
    $thisItem.click(function () {
        $parent.submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Cheers kalley, your a star. I knew it was something like that. I think triggering the submit after is also a good route too.